# Power Monitoring Physics Experiment

Tags: power, power-supply, sensor, analog-to-digital

Hi i am just planning a Physics experiment where i accelerate Ionized Gases onto a target sample.
For this Experiment i need to monitor the power constantly over a week or longer.
For my later data analysis i need accurate Messurements of power consumption, heat, light intensity, and many more. I have one main power input wich will be connected to a power supply that doesnt support datalogging. The main input voltage will be arround 200-300V and the Current might spike to values about 5-10 A. 
I figured everything out now except for the powermonitoring i am not sure what i should do in this situation because most sensors are not rated for these values.
I hope one of you guys might come up with an idea 
I apologize for my bad english spelling 
With best regards 
weiserhase

Comment: Details missing: `The main input voltage will be arround 200-300V and the Current might spike to values about 5-10 A` - AC or DC?

Comment: Before we can give you a good answer what are the tolerances for time, voltage and current. I do it all the time but I use a current probe in my teck scope. If you have access to a scope of this type you could have it generate a file for you with all the information. The other inputs could be used to capture other data as well. File etc depends on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I bought this unit for home power monitoring : https://a.aliexpress.com/_m0fEuEq. Still not tested it but looks something similar to what you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).